# android automating build using Hudson + third party libraries

Tags: android, eclipse, jenkins

I am working alongside with two other developers in an android application. In the application we use other third-party libraries like SlidingMenu.

In eclipse we should include the SlidingMenu project and point our application to use this project as library.

Now I want to automate the building of the application using Hudson(Jenkins) but I have no Idea how I will deal with the dependence libraries like SlidingMenu.

Any Ideas

Comment: I wrote an answer below, but you should check out http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 1):

So long as you can build your app on the command line (e.g. using the Ant or Gradle build systems for Android), then you can build your app in Jenkins.

For the Ant build system, all you need to do is place your dependency JARs in the "libs" directory.

Or if you're using library projects, the Eclipse plugin should have already added the required entries to your project.properties file.